# How to build an ajax web application which gracefully falls back if browser does not support javascript?

Tags: jquery, ajax, unobtrusive-javascript

Sorry for long title but my concern is with constructing an ajax based application.

I have a version one of this application which does not require javascript to function, I want to migrate this to use ajax for various resources that come from a 3rd party soap web service.

How can I build an ajax application which when the browser does not have javascript or has it disabled will still function properly? (The server side code is tested and in production so I do have a solid foundation to fall back on just not sure how to do this in a graceful maner.)

I am familiar with all the tools (client and server side) and plan on using jquery framework but not sure about the part where javascript isn't running on the browser and how my application can still function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery is very good at supporting "graceful degredation" for web apps.  You can apply the AJAX functionality to your non-javascript page by adding functionality after the page has loaded (through use of the $(document.ready() method).  You'll need to catch the triggers on your page that would cause a page to reload ('click()', 'submit()', etc), stop the traditional browser event from firing ('preventDefault()'), and make calls to you AJAX functions.  You may need to update and/or construct a few API wrappers or web service functions (depending on your environment) to generate responses that the AJAX functions can absorb and then render out to the browser.

This is a very common and well-practiced form of web app development.  I suggest starting off with the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) and if you run into issues, post specific questions (with code snippets) back here and I'm sure you'll get lots of answers and feedback.  Good luck!

Comment: I have jquery experience.  But your answer seems to just tough on the issues I mentioned in my answer instead of addressing them in any concrete fashion.  Can you explain: 1. how to apply ajax functionality to a non-javascript page?

Comment: If you're looking for a concrete answer, I can only give examples. And there are too many examples to list out. There are many ways and it depends on the functionality of the app.  Off the top of my head:  what are you using as the means to trigger the AJAX call?  Are you using form submission?  Anchor tags?  Mouse events such as drag and drop?  Or are you doing a map-style interface?  Or just about any other interface you can think of...  There's far too much that you *could* be doing that I can't give you an answer with enough detail to satisfy the question.  I suggest posting a code sample.

Comment: A lot of the reason for moving to ajax is to reduce the time part of the page loads.  Since the soap request can be delayed we do not want the user waiting for the entire page to load when we could make ajax calls for all soap resources that way the frame of the page can load and the content from soap will come when the request is satisfied and sent to the client browser.  Perhaps a few onclicks/form submissions would be ajax based as well.  As far as code goes I just stared with the new stuff, all I would have to show now is some php classes calling soap server for requests and serving html.